# How to access data from json file in angularjs factory and return

Tags: angularjs, json

json file which contains my app_key and app_secret, I have written factory service to make available app_key and app_secret everywhere. but I am not getting in correct format,
here is my factory method

```
.factory('UserService', function($http) {
        var obj ={}; 
        $http.get('config.json').success(function(data) {
            obj.app_key = data.app_key;
            obj.app_secret=data.app_secret;
        })
        console.log(obj);
        return {
            app_key : obj.app_key,
            app_secret : obj.app_secret
        }
    })
```

Here is my config.json file

```
{
    "url": "",
    "app_key": "myappkeycode",
    "app_secret": "appsecretcodehere"
}
```

I want my app key and app secret to be accessed everywhere with `userService.app_key` and `userService.app_secret`
Whats wrong I am doing dont know I am getting object but in following format

```
Object {}
app_key:"appkeycoming keyhere",
app_secret:"appsecretcominghere"
```

Which is not working as you see first object is empty.

Comment: It is asynchronous. Put a `console.log(data)` inside the success function

Comment: data is coming but I cant return in format I want

Comment: Have you tried my answer ?

Answer (score 0):

`$http.get` is an asynchronous call. Then you are calling the value of `app_key` and `app_secret` before being set inside the success function.

You should replace your factory by this

```
module.factory('userService', function() {
    var fac = {};

    fac.getConfig = $http.get('config.json');

    return fac;
});
```

And call it like this

```
userService.getConfig().then(function(resp){
    var obj = {};
    obj.app_key = resp.app_key;
    obj.app_secret = resp.app_secret;
})
```